# Simple Python API Call - Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to use the following API using the Requests module:

https://www.planit.org.uk/api/

My code is the following (using the example they provided on the API doc):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://planit.org.uk//api/applics/json?auth=Hackney&start_date=2010-10-01&end_date=2010-10-02&pg_sz=10"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
```

And I get the following error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='planit.org.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/applics/json?auth=Hackney&start_date=2010-10-01&end_date=2010-10-02&pg_sz=10 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'planit.org.uk'. (_ssl.c:1000)")))

Can anyone establish why I'm getting this error?

Comment: That host does not have a proper security certificate.  You can use `requests.get(url, verify=False)` to tell requests not to verify the host certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate isn't configured for that hostname, only `www.planit.org.uk`. Check with a tool [like this](https://www.digicert.com/help/) which can explain in more detail.

PSA: When using both "dub" and "dubless" versions of your host, be sure to provision a certificate accordingly. This is an easy thing to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate returned by the server is valid for "www.planit.org.uk" but not for "planit.org.uk" (without "www"). This might be due to a misconfiguration of the server, but it might also be that it wasn't supposed to be called with "planit.org.uk", i.e. a misconfiguration at the client.